# DataGridViewImageColumn, images flickering

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewimagecolumn

I have a DataGridView bound to a DataTable on my Windows Form. I want to insert an unbound DataGridViewImagecolumn to it and set the images according to the value of another column. Image is set in DataGidView_CellFormating event. Code is as follows

```
DataGridView dgvResult = new DataGridView();
dgvResult.DataSource = dtResult;
DataGridViewImageColumn imageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
imageColumn.Width = 40;
imageColumn.Name = "Image";
imageColumn.HeaderText = "";
dgvResult.Columns.Insert(0, imageColumn);

    private void dgvResult_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvResult.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Image")
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dgvResult.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            if (Utils.isNumeric(row.Cells["CM_IsExport"].Value.ToString()) && Int32.Parse(row.Cells["CM_IsExport"].Value.ToString()) == 1)
            {
                    row.Cells["Image"].Value = Properties.Resources.export16;
            }
            else { row.Cells["Image"].Value = Properties.Resources.plain16; }
        }
    }
```

Everything is working fine. My problem is that the images shown in cells are flickering. Anybody know why?

Comment: Flickering? Can you post a video/gif? Do you mean the iPhone's effect (the one when you hold a random icon)

Comment: Not like iPhone's icon flickering. But feels like it is refreshing it every second. I don't know how to post video.

Comment: Oh I understand. Not sure about the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flickering is happening because you are setting the image in `CellFormatting` event handler.

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),the `CellFormatting` event occurs every time each cell is painted, so you should avoid lengthy processing when handling this event.

You could set the image by handling `DataBindingComplete` or `CellValueChanged` events according to your need.

You could also enable `DoubleBuffering` for the `DataGridView` by creating a custom `DataGridView` or through reflection for the instance you are using.

```
class CustomDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    public CustomDataGridView()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I moved the code to RowsAdded event. It is OK now.

Comment: The flickering problem is solved by moving the code to RowsAdded event. But when the number of records is more ( Say 200 records), it takes 2 to 3 seconds for the grid to load. with CellFormating event, it was loading quickly.

Comment: @user1542352  Are you looping the `DataGridView.Rows` to set the image in the RowsAdded event?

Comment: Yes. for (int i = e.RowIndex; i < e.RowIndex + e.RowCount; i++) {//Check condition and set image}